# Free/inexpensive beat grid drum machine plugins for GarageBand?

Tags: osx, music-production

I'm looking for free or at least inexpensive (under $15) beat grid drum machine plugins for GarageBand.  These plugins **must work with the new GarageBand (v10+)**.

High quality drum kit samples are of course preferred, although I'm willing to accept what I can for my price range.  Standalone applications that can export GarageBand compatible loops are also acceptable if they maintain a smooth workflow.

Optional suggestions for higher-end (or more optimal) drum machines to consider using in the future are also welcome.